# Backbone.LocalStorage saves but does not fetch collection using Knockback

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, local-storage, backbone.js-collections, knockback.js

Backbone.LocalStorage stores a list of players client-side when calling `create` on a `players` collection, but the stored models are not being fetched later, even though I can inspect them in localStorage. I can call `@collections.players.localStorage.findAll()` to retrieve all the stored objects and manually push them onto my collection.

```
class App.Models.Player extends Backbone.Model
    defaults:
        name: 'Unnamed'
        team: 'Unassigned'

class App.Collections.Players extends Backbone.Collection
    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage('players')
    model: App.Models.Player

class App.ViewModels.Game extends kb.ViewModel

    constructor: ->
        @collections =
            players: new App.Collections.Players()

        @collections.players.fetch(
            success: (collection) =>

                console.log(collection) # shows none
                console.log(@collections.players.localStorage.findAll())
                    # shows all the stored players
        )

        # @players below is rendered by a foreach in a knockout template
        @players = kb.collectionObservable @collections.players, { view_model: App.ViewModels.Player }

    addPlayer: -> # called when a button is pressed
        @collections.players.create(new App.Models.Player({ name: 'New Player' }))
        return
```

Why is Knockback unable to fetch the stored entities automatically?

The following call manually retrieves all objects:

```
_.each @collections.players.localStorage.findAll(), (elem) =>
    @collections.players.add(elem)
```